# Add a Key Value Pair to an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, keyvaluepair

If I had an array as such:

```
var myarray = [];

myarray.push({
    "Name": 'Adam',
    "Age": 33
});

myarray.push({
    "Name": 'Emily',
    "Age": 32
});
```

This gives me an array where I can pull out values like `myarray[0].Name` which would give me "Adam".

However, after this array is built, how can I add an "address" field with a value of "somewhere street" into the array at position [0], so that my fields in that object at position zero are now `Name`, `Age`, and `Address` with corresponding values?

I was thinking `splice()` somehow but couldn't find an example using objects, just examples with simple arrays.

Comment: Why can't you do `myarray[0].address = "somewhere street"`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply add properties ("fields") on the fly.

Try

```
myarray[0].Address = "123 Some St.";
```

or

```
myarray[0]["Address"] = "123 Some St.";
```

```js
var myarray = [];

myarray.push({
    "Name": 'Adam',
    "Age": 33
});

myarray.push({
    "Name": 'Emily',
    "Age": 32
});

myarray[0]["Address"] = "123 Some St.";

console.log( JSON.stringify( myarray, null, 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 9):

Along with a single value like

```
myarray[0].address = "your address";
```

You could even add a nested property on the fly as below:

```
myarray[0].address = { presentAddress: "my present address..." };
```

and get the value as `myarray[0].address.presentAddress;`.