# Adding keypairs to an array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this Array of objects, and I am having problems adding more key-pairs to the objects in typescript.

For Example I have this Array.

```
 accountsOptions:any = [
                          {'data': 
                                    {
                                      'adidas': null, 
                                      'google': null
                                    }
                          }
                        ];
```

And I want to add more here

```
 accountsOptions:any = [
                              {'data': 
                                        {
                                          'adidas': null, 
                                          'google': null,
                                          'nike': null,
                                          'apple': null
                                        }
                              }
                            ];
```

the new values are coming from another array, how can I loop(efficiently) this and dynamically add more key-pairs? I am new to typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of array methods and check if the object contains the property, if it does not contain add the property to the object..

check the following code snippet

```js
"use strict";
var accountsOptions = [
    { 'data': {
            'adidas': null,
            'google': null
        }
    }
];
function addProperty(propertyName) {
    accountsOptions.map(function (account) {
        if (!account.data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
            account.data[propertyName] = null;
        }
    });
}
addProperty('nike');
console.log(accountsOptions)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference to the `data` object:

```
var data:any = accountsOptions[0].data;
```

...and then you loop through your array, for instance with a boring old `for` loop (but you have **lots** of options there; see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) to know what they are):

```
for (var i:number = 0; i < yourArray.length; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

...and in the loop, you use brackets notation (see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)) to add properties to the `data` object:

```
data[yourArray[i]] = null;
```

E.g.:

```
var data:any = accountsOptions[0].data;
for (var i:number = 0; i < yourArray.length; ++i) {
    data[yourArray[i]] = null;
}
```

But again, you have several options for the loop. Here's another one:

```
var data:any = accountsOptions[0].data;
yourArray.forEach((entry:string) => {
    data[entry] = null;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `accountsOptions[0].data.nike = null`.

Obviously you can loop through `accountsOptions` using a `for` loop.

You can have more idea from these SO:
[Add a Key Value Pair to an array of objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768280/add-a-key-value-pair-to-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) and 
[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)